# Unable to upload some files to mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mime-types

I've got an internal wiki (airgapped) where we hope to upload a variety of configuration files and other non-standard files. Rather than needing to explicitly allow the extension, I want to allow any extension as long as its not in the blacklist. Additionally, I want to disable MIME checking because it thinks certain files are something they are not and doesn't know what to do with them.

I have tried placing these settings in my LocalSettings.php file:

```
$wgVerifyMimeType = false;
$wgCheckFileExtensions = false;
$wgStrictFileExtensions = false;
```

However, these appear to do absolutely nothing. I am still prohibited from uploading a file with an extension not explicitly allowed, and I also continue to get the error "This file is a corrupt or otherwise unreadable ZIP file. It cannot be properly checked for security." (Its a Chrome CRX extension file).

What am I missing here? The mediawiki manual and the other articles I have read tell me to do what I've tried, but its not working. I am running mediawiki 1.37.1.

Comment: You may have to set something in $wgFileBlacklist and $wgMimeTypeBlacklist, just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `$wgProhibitedFileExtensions = []` and `$wgVerifyMimeTypeIE = false`.

To enable `.crx`, set `$wgAllowJavaUploads = true`.

In some other cases, you may also need `$wgDisableUploadScriptChecks`.

Warning to readers: all of the above is dangerous.